# Как ставить ударение в слове ТОРРЕНТ?

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия, заимствования

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильное ударение в слове "ТОРРЕНТ". Везде ставят ударение на первом слоге, но, по законам русского словообразования, мне кажется, правильнее ударять на последний слог. В словарях данного слова не нашла.

Comment: Говорю тóррент.

Answer (score 2):

Нормы у этого слова в русском языке нет, есть в английском (на первый слог) откуда оно заимствовано, но он нам не указ. Как следствие на данный момент правильно произносить так,  как удобнее лично вам. Я, как человек слабо знакомый с английским, предпочту торрЕнт (с твёрдым [p]), по аналогии с комплимент, ангажемент, рудимент, патент и другими русскими словами оканчивающимися на "-ент".

Comment: А как же Вы произносите импичмент, менеджмент, истеблишмент?

Comment: Кроме давно русифицированного импичмент, эти слова я произношу с двойным ударением.

Comment: Вы делаете две ошибки. 1. Норма сначала складывается, потом фиксируется. Фактически она уже сложилась. 2. Даже пока норма не установлена логично пользоваться нормой языка-источника. Так обычно и поступают.  
Ну и не могу не заметить, что Вы смешиваете слова на "-мент" со всеми словами на "-ент". Первые - как правило французского происхождения, но даже они могу произноситься по-разному, в зависимости от пути непосредственного заимствования. Что до вторых, то тут вообще - полная свобода. ДевЕлопмент, Имиджмент, парлАмент, рЕгент и проч.

Comment: Девелопомент и имиджмент с двойным, остальные с ординарным. По правилам русской фонетики, [э] не под ударением звучит также как [и]или [ы] не под ударением (не будем касаться различия фонетических школ, но заменяться эти звуки без изменения смысла должны). Вы спокойно поймёте слова девЕлопминт, Имиджминт, тОрынт? Я для себя не вижу причин ставить 2 ударения тО-рЭнт в слове из двух слогов. По опыту общения, мне чаще попадались именно с ударением на второй слог.

Answer (score 1):

1. В английском огромное количество слов, ударение в которых падает совсем не на первый слог.
2. Ударение в языке-источнике не указ для  языка-приемника.
3. Слово torrent произносится с ударением на **первый слог**, и по факту все так произнозносят и в русском. Причин для пересмотра сложившегося произношения я не вижу.

Comment: Мне более привычно слышать это слово с ударением на втором слоге. 

Comment: Вопрос интересный. Я слышал это слово "торрент" то с ударением на первый слог, то на второй. Интересно было бы узнать, как правильно.

Comment: >Я слышал это слово "торрент" то с ударением на первый слог, то на второй. 
  
Интересно бы послушать. Тех, кто ударяет на второй.

Comment: > интересно бы послушать. Тех, кто ударяет на второй  
Хорошо, пришлю Вам аудиофайл. Голосов на 3-4 минимум.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что слово "торрент" английского происхождения ("torrent" - "поток"), а в английском есть жесткое правило: ударение ставится на первый слог. Поэтому слово "торрент" никак не подчиняется правилам ударения русского языка и должно произноситься так, как в оригинале - т***о***ррент.

Comment: В русском языке огромное количество заимствованных английских слов: агент, комплимент, рудимент и т.п. - и ударение в них ставится все же не на первый слог, а именно по правилам русского языка.

Answer (score 0):

«Грамота.ру» утверждает, что на первом слоге. Не верить ей причин у меня нет. Кроме того, это слово — неологизм. И пока оно в нашем языке не прижилось настолько, чтобы появиться в словарях, следует отдавать предпочтение варианту, который отражает произношение в английском языке.

Comment: Почему же неологизм, обычное заимствование.

Comment: @shampar Заимствование - один из способов образования неологизмов.

Comment: Не все заимствования неологизмы. То, что слово это заимствовано, — сомнений нет. Но почему же непременно неологизм?